# How many Star Wars CCGs have there been?

Tags: star-wars-lcg

How many TCG/CCG/etc. games have been officially licensed by Star Wars? I'm looking for names, dates, and publishers.

In the 90's Decipher created the Star Wars CCG. Around the time of the Episode 1 brand reboot, Decipher also started printing the Young Jedi CCG. Quickly thereafter they lost the license and Wizards made the Star Wars TCG. I think there was another close to this time as well.

Other recent ones I have heard of are Star Wars: The Card Game and Star Wars: Destiny (both from Fantasy Flight).

This churn seems very contrary to the idea of an extensible card game. Bonus points if you have any references to explanations for this product churn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching on Board Game Geek comes up with the following hits:

1. Star Wars Customizable Card Game (1995, Decipher) - card game
2. Star Wars: Jedi Knights CCG (2001, Decipher) - card game
3. Board Game: Star Wars: Trading Card Game (2002 - 2005, WotC) - card game (+ versions for Attack of the Clones, Empire Strikes Back and Revenge of the Sith)
4. Star Wars PocketModel TCG (2007, Topps / WizKids) - mini and card game
5. Star Wars Force Attax (2010, Topps) - card game
6. Star Wars the Card Game (2012, FFG) - living card game
7. Star Wars Destiny (2012, FFG) - card and dice game
8. Something Wild! Star Wars (2021-2022, Funko) - mini + card game (I'm not sure this is a CCG (4 versions))
9. Board Game: Star Wars: Unlimited – Spark of Rebellion (2024, FFG) - card game

EDIT: My search missed (thanks @ConMan)
Young Jedi: Collectible Card Game (1999, Decipher) - card game

There is also the print and play: Star Wars: Stolen Plans Card Game (2006) https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/23878/star-wars-stolen-plans-card-game

I don't have a source, but it looks like the license for Star Wars card games started with Decipher (1995 - 2002), then went to WotC (2002-2007), the  Topps 2007-2012) and now rests with FFG (2012-present).

[BGG Advanced Search (title: star wars; filter no expansions; game category: Card Game, Collectible Components)](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&advsearch=1&objecttype=boardgame&q=star%20wars&include%5Bdesignerid%5D=&geekitemname=&geekitemname=&include%5Bpublisherid%5D=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bminage%5D%5Bmax%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bnumvoters%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bnumweights%5D%5Bmin%5D=&colfiltertype=&searchuser=&nosubtypes%5B%5D=boardgameexpansion&range%5Bminplayers%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bmaxplayers%5D%5Bmin%5D=&playerrangetype=normal&range%5Bleastplaytime%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Bplaytime%5D%5Bmax%5D=&propertyids%5B%5D=1002&propertyids%5B%5D=1044&B1=Submit)

Comment: Decipher also had the [Young Jedi CCG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2130/young-jedi-collectible-card-game).

Comment: Thanks added Young Jedi CCG